# Postman - Get response value using variable key

Tags: javascript, json, postman, postman-testcase

I've created a GET request in Postman that returns some data in a JSON format. I want to get the JSON response value for every key that contains a specific substring.

This is the code I've been trying:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var keys = Object.keys(jsonData);

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) 
{
    if(keys[i].has("_number"))
    { 
       console.log(jsonData.keys[i]);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** The issue isn't with the substring recognition, but with the return of the values. If I try to get a value using a specific key in the condition (e.g. jsonData.Id) it works just fine. It just doesn't work when I'm trying to use a variable.

Comment: What's the response body?

Comment: I don't know if it makes any difference but I'm using Runner to run the request. The response I'm getting is something like this
`
{
    "Id": 12345,
    "name": "test",
    "date": "2020-05-20",
    "f1_number" : "1",
    "f2_number" : "2",
    "a1_number" : "1",
    "a2_number" : "2",
    .
    .
    .
}
`

Comment: Hi i have edited my answer, hope that will help you, issue is here `console.log(jsonData[keys[i]])`

Comment: Thank you! That solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this way

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
var keys = Object.keys(jsonData);

for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) 
{
    if(keys[i].includes('_number'))
    { 
       console.log(jsonData[keys[i]]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

has() is only searching for an exact key within a map. Try this for checking a substring:

```
if(keys[i].indexOf("_number") !== -1)
{ 
   console.log(jsonData.keys[i]);
}
```

or even the string function includes()

```
if(keys[i].includes("_number"))
{ 
   console.log(jsonData.keys[i]);
}
```

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be with the substring check. I tried your suggestions just to make sure but the values are still not returning. If I try to get a value using a specific key in the condition (e.g. jsonData.Id) it works just fine. It just doesn't work when I'm trying to use a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different method but this would give the same output in the Postman Console:

```
_.each(Object.entries(jsonData), (item) => {
    if(item[0].includes('_number')) {
        console.log(item[1])
    }
})
```